# Prompting user with a print after each Switch-case except case: "0 exit"

Tags: java

Instead of making it blank each time the user is finished with a case, I've added a println("Next command?>") in the runCommandLoop method as a cheap solution to my problem. But that also means when case "0" or "exit" is choosen, "Next command?>" is printed out one last time BEFORE shutting down.

Simply put I want it to prompt after every case except "0 shutdown".

Calling the startup method is another option as well I guess but that doesn't make much difference either.

```
private void startup() {
    System.out.println("\nCommand?>\n" + "1: register new dog\n" + "2: increase age\n" + "3: list dogs\n"
            + "4: remove dog\n" + "0: exit\n");
}

private void runCommandLoop() {
    boolean done;
    do {
        String command = readCommand();
        done = handleCommand(command);
        System.out.println("\nNext command?>");
    } while (!done);
}

private String readCommand() {
    String command = input.registerString();
    return command;
}

private boolean handleCommand(String command) {
    switch (command) {

    case "1":
    case "register new dog":
        dogList.registerDog();
        break;

    case "2":
    case "increase age":
        dogList.increaseAge();
        break;

    case "3":
    case "list dogs":
        dogList.listDogs();
        break;

    case "4":
    case "remove dog":
        dogList.removeDog();
        break;

    case "0":
    case "exit":
        return true;
    default:
        printMenu();
    }
    return false;
}

private void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("Error: wrong command\n" + "The available commands are:\n" + "1: register new dog\n"
            + "2: increase age\n" + "3: list dogs\n" + "4: remove dog\n" + "0: exit");
    return;
}

private void closeDown() {
    System.out.println("Shutting down...");
    input.closeInput();

}

private void run() {
    startup();
    runCommandLoop();
    closeDown();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface startup = new Interface();
    startup.run();
}
```

In case you need to see what the dogList methods do (the arraylist variable name is just temporary):

```
public void registerDog() {
    String name = input.registerStringLoop("Name");
    String breed = input.registerStringLoop("Breed");
    int weight = input.registerIntPrompt("Weight");
    int age = input.registerIntPrompt("Age");
    Dog dog = new Dog(name, breed, age, weight);
    doggoList.add(dog);
    System.out.println(dog.getName() + " has been added to the register.\n" + dog.toString());

}

public void listDogs() {
    if (doggoList.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Error: no dogs found");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Smallest tail length to display?>");
        int smallestTailLength = input.registerInt();
        sortDogs();
        if (smallestTailLength == 0) {
            System.out.println(doggoList);
        } else
            for (Dog s : doggoList) {
                if (s.getTailLength() >= smallestTailLength)
                    System.out.println(s);
            }
    }
}

public void increaseAge() {
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the dog?>");
    String dogName = input.registerString();
    for (Dog s : doggoList) {
        if (s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(dogName)) {
            s.increaseAge();
            sortDogs();
            System.out.println(s.getName() + " is now " + s.getAge() + " years old.");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
if (!done){
    System.out.println("\nNext command?>");
}
```

Comment: Damn I tunnel-visioned so hard. Thank you so much!!